# Creating Polynomial Class in Python

Tags: python

I am currently working on creating a Polynomial class that includes **add** , **mul** and **eval** methods. I'm currently stuck on the addition portion, if someone could give me some help on how to get that figured out that would be greatly appreciated. Everything currently works without errors but when I do p3 = p1 + p2 and I print p3 I get back the two lists together. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Polynomial(object):

    def __init__(self, *coeffs, num = 0):

        self.coeffs = list(coeffs) # turned into a list

        assert (type(num) is type(1)) 
        self.num = num

    # Needs to be operator overload
    '''
    def __mul__(self, other):
    '''

    def __eval__(self, other, coeff, x):
        result = coeff[-1]
        for i in range(-2, -len(coeff)-1, -1):
            result = result * x + coeff[i]
        return result


    def __add__(self, other):

        assert type(other) is Polynomial

        num = self.coeffs + other.coeffs

        return Polynomial(num)


    def __sub__(self, other):

        assert type(other) is Polynomial
        num = self.coeffs - other.coeffs

        return Polynomial(num)




    def __represntation__(self):
        return "Polynomial" + str(self.coeffs)   

    def __str__(self):
        rep = ""    
        degree = len(self.coeffs) - 1
        rep += str(self.coeffs[0]) + "x^" + str(degree)       
        for i in range(1, len(self.coeffs)-1):
            coeff = self.coeffs[i]
            if coeff < 0:
                rep += " - " +  str(-coeff) + "x^" + str(degree - i)
            else:
                rep += " + " +  str(coeff) + "x^" + str(degree - i)

            if self.coeffs[-1] < 0:
                rep += " - " + str(-self.coeffs[-1])
        else:
            rep += " + " + str(self.coeffs[-1])  
        return rep
```

Comment: what should __add__ actually do? combine the values, add each one together in sequence, or what

Comment: `type(x) is y` doesn't allow for subclassing; use `isinstance(x, y)` instead.

Comment: Don't invent double-underscore names; `__add__` and `__mul__` have a specific meaning in the language; `__eval__` and `__representation__` do not (though you probably want `__repr__` for the latter).

Comment: @chepner It's a reasonable assumption that OP is using `__add__` and `__mul__` intentionally to override those operators

Comment: Right, I wasn't clear. You are *meant* to override them, precisely *because* they have a specific meaning. Names like `__eval__` that don't have a preexisting meaning should not be introduced.

Comment: What do you think double underscores in functions names do?

Comment: I was intending to override the operators add and sub, as for eval, that was in there because it was a function required by my assignment for the class this is for.

Comment: Your class assignment is requiring you to implement an `__eval__` method? .. Yikes. I think it should be `__call__` instead and accept `self` and a single argument, `x` (the point to evaluate your polynomial at).

Comment: that makes more sense looking at it, I understand why __eval__ would not be a good method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
num = self.coeffs + other.coeffs
```

Adding one list to another list *concatenates* them. To simply add corresponding elements to each other, you'd want to do

```
from itertools import zip_longest

...

num = [a + b for (a, b) in zip_longest(self.coeffs, other.coeffs, fillvalue=0)]
```

We use `zip_longest()` instead of the more generic `zip()` because one polynomial is possibly longer than the other and we don't want to ruin it. Either one of them will group together the corresponding elements so that we can easily add them and make a list of those.

You would do something similar for subtraction.

Comment: how would I implement that into my code to print out the polynomial after the addition. I imported the itertools and now I just need to print the polynomial following addition.

Comment: `return Polynomial(*num)`, probably. The `*` operator will decompose the list into a sequence of elements, which is what the `Polynomial.__init__()` wants.

Comment: Thank you for the help, that worked exactly how I wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add two lists.

```
def __add__(self, other):

    assert type(other) is Polynomial
    assert len(self.coeffs) != len(other.coeffs)

    new_ceffs = [item1 + item2 for (item1, item2) in zip(self.coeffs, other.coeffs)]

    return Polynomial(new_ceffs)
```

Comment: Why do you assert the coefficient lengths be un-equal? What if I want to add `x+1` with `4x+5`? Also, `zip` will only give you items until you reach the last item in the shortest list. This is why the previous answer used `itertools.zip_longest` with a `fillvalue` of `0`.

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica I like your elegant approach, from the code provided by the questioner, correct me, if I am wrong, I don't think he considered the case `x+1`, so if using your code, the questioner will need to rewrite the `init` when apply it to his/her code to make sure it can handle the case without coeffs.

Answer (score 0):

you should reverse the order of coefficients passed to your constructor so that indexes in the `self.coeffs` list correspond to the exponents.  This would simplify the rest of your code and allow you to use zip_longest for additions and subtractions.

When you get to other operations however, I think you will realize that your internal structure would be easier to manage if it was a dictionary.  A dictionary is more permissive of missing entries thus avoiding preoccupations of allocating spaces for new indexes.

```
class Polynomial(object):

    def __init__(self, *coeffs):
        self.coeffs = {exp:c for exp,c in enumerate(coeffs[::-1])}
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        assert type(other) is Polynomial
        result = Polynomial(0)
        result.coeffs = {**self.coeffs}
        for exp,c in other.coeffs.items():
            result.coeffs[exp] = result.coeffs.get(exp,0) + c
        return result

    def __sub__(self, other):
        assert type(other) is Polynomial
        result = Polynomial(0)
        result.coeffs = {**self.coeffs}
        for exp,c in other.coeffs.items():
            result.coeffs[exp] = result.coeffs.get(exp,0) - c
        return result

    def __mul__(self, other):
        assert type(other) is Polynomial
        result = Polynomial(0)
        for exp1,c1 in self.coeffs.items():
            for exp2,c2 in other.coeffs.items():
                result.coeffs[exp1+exp2] = result.coeffs.get(exp1+exp2,0) + c1*c2
        return result
        
    def __representation__(self):
        return "Polynomial" + str(self.coeffs)   

    def __str__(self):
        result = [""]+[f"{c}x^{i}" for i,c in sorted(self.coeffs.items()) if c]+[""]
        result = "+".join(reversed(result))
        result = result.replace("+1x","+x")
        result = result.replace("-1x","-x")
        result = result.replace("x^0","")
        result = result.replace("x^1+","x+")
        result = result.replace("+-","-")
        result = result.strip("+")
        result = result.replace("+"," + ")
        result = result[:1]+result[1:].replace("-"," - ")
        return result.strip()
```